# Defining property conforming to View inheritation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm inheriting the protocol `View` so that instances need to implement the function `fetchData`, like this:

```
import SwiftUI

protocol FunctionalityView: View {
    
    func fetchData() async throws
}
```

I'm trying to store an instance conforming to `FunctionalityView` as a property in a view implementation, like this:

```
@State var functionalityView: any FunctionalityView
```

Ultimately, I would like to embed functionalityView in a view, like this:

```
ScrollView {
    functionalityView
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'any FunctionalityView' cannot conform to 'View'

I also tried defining `functionalityView` with `some` and without `any` but had no luck so far.

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you should be using another view as the `@State` of your view... The `fetchData` functionality should be separated from the view and be part of your model instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: You can’t make this work. Holding a view in a State will make it unstable and will be “out of date”

Comment: _Why_ do you think you need to hold a view as State?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Using `@State` doesn't make sense, indeed. I solved my question in another way (not using protocol inheritance). Still keen to know how I could have made this work without using `@State`, though. It would have resulted in the same error, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `any FunctionalityView` is known as an “existential”. It is a sort of “box” that can hold any value whose type conforms to `FunctionalityView`.

Existentials have a major limitation: they do not conform to protocols.<sup>1</sup> The type `any FunctionalityView` does not conform to the `FunctionalityView` protocol, nor to the `View` protocol.

One workaround is to make the containing view generic, like this:

```
struct MyView<F: FunctionalityView>: View {
    @State var functionalityView: F
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            functionalityView
        }
    }
}
```

Another workaround is wrapping `functionalityView` in `AnyView` when needed to treat it as a `View`:

```
extension FunctionalityView {
    func asAnyView() -> AnyView {
        // Inside a FunctionalityView method, `self` is
        // always its true runtime type, not an existential,
        // so self's View conformance is available.
        AnyView(self)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State var functionalityView: any FunctionalityView
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            functionalityView.asAnyView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Footnote 1. There is one exception: `any Error` conforms to `Error`, thanks to special cases in the compiler and runtime. This conformance was added as part of [SE-0235: Add Result to the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0235-add-result.md#adding-swifterror-self-conformance), to support types like `Result<Int, Error>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This clarifies a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`@State` is a property that holds the source of truth for your `View`. It should *not* be another view.

In your case, you might want to hold a property that represents the view you want to display, using an `enum` for example:

```
protocol FunctionalityView: View {
    
    func fetchData() async throws
}

enum ViewType {
    case view1, view2
}

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State private var viewType = ViewType.view1
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            switch viewType {
            case .view1:
                View1()
            case .view2:
                View2()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: FunctionalityView {
    var body: some View {
        Text("view1")
    }
    
    func fetchData() async throws {
        
    }
}

struct View2: FunctionalityView {
    var body: some View {
        Text("view2")
    }
    func fetchData() async throws {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it another way (but partially similar to your answer). I discontinued using protocol (inheritance), at least.